# Create dataframes based on column values and delete rows in current dataframe that were used in creating new ones

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with an id column of products that I need to separate into new dataframes, saving them on separated csvs and keep the dataframe with the rows that were not used to save in another csv, excluding the one that is now in the new dataframes. What's the best way to do this?

Df_original

```
    Id value Product_id
0    1   123         7
1    2   514         9
2    3   234         1
3    4   912         9
4    5   325         1
5    6   301         7
6    7   325         1
7    8   301         9
```

then i create two new dataframes for product id 7 and 9

Df_new_pd_7

```
    Id value Product_id
0    1   123         7
5    6   301         7
```

Df_new_pd_9

```
Id value Product_id
1    2   514         9
3    4   912         9
7    8   301         9
```

so my original dataframe will look like this

Df_original

```
    Id value Product_id
2    3   234         1
4    5   325         1
6    7   325         1
```

Comment: `dfs = {k:d for k,d in df.groupby('Product_id')}`, then `dfs[7]` and so on...

Comment: @G.Anderson that removes the selected column from the dataframe and leaves the none mentioned columns. The OP is wanting to filter into new dataframes

Comment: @QuangHoang what about if there are more than 3 product IDs in the intial DF?

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover yes, that works for any number of `Product_id`.

Comment: @QuangHoang if I would need 2 of 4 separated out?